# "sendmail" command bug. Getting distorted mails also "!" chars are added

Tags: java, email, unix, sendmail, aix

I am creating HTML format for sending email in Java and using below UNIX script to send it:

```
(       echo "Subject: Test";
        echo "To: test@mail.com";
        echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
        echo "Content-Type: text/html";
        echo "Content-Disposition: inline";
        echo "";
        cat HTML_Body
) | sendmail test@mail.com
```

But HTML_Body is getting distorted when I am receiving mails from this `UNIX` command, also some special characters like **`!`** are also getting added along with the body, also the alignment of some cells are getting distorted.

When I am copying the HTML_Body from Java console, the body is created properly, but after `sendmail` command it is getting distorted.

I am using `outlook`, and Unix version is : `AIX serverName 1 6`

Also please suggest some other options for sending mail through UNIX or using Java. I tried creating file from Java and sending it as an attachment but, in that file also, content was getting distorted.

***[Edit]* Adding more details, this bug is exact the same explained [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31496) for *sendmail* command.**

Comment: I'm failing to see how this question is Java related...

Comment: @icza it is because, as I said, I am sending HTML_Body, which is created in Java to Unix.

Comment: Most likely a character encoding issue. Can you show us the Java code that creates the HTML_Body?

Comment: @icza I am using simple `for` loop that creates `<tr>` and `<td>` and appending it to `StringBuffer` object and then by using `toString` method I am passing that String as HTML_Body

Comment: @icza can this be any server configuration issue?

Comment: Can you still show me your Java code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60890/discussion-between-vishrant-and-icza).

Comment: This is almost certainly an encoding issue. Make sure absolutely everything is utf8.

Comment: Does `HTML_Body` begin with a blank line? If not, where's the delimiter between message headers and message body?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson No HTML_Body does not begin with a blank line, I have used `echo ""` instead for the space between header and the body

Comment: That was not shown in the question, earlier. Was that in the original code? If not, did adding it make a difference?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson my mistake, I missed in question, but it was in original code.

Comment: @icza you can see the sample code in the link I provided after edit.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having issues with long html, some special chars were added. After I inserted a newline after every `<tr>`, the problem went away

Answer (score 0):

### Sendmail line length limits

Sendmail as provided by sendmail.org imposes limit on line lengths (990 or 2048 bytes) and breaks longer lines.

You may
* use tool like `mimencode` to encode body in quoted-printable format
  (requires changes in mime headers)
**OR**
* use tool like `tidy` to reformat your html file with line length limits

BTW There should be an empty line between email headers and email body (`echo ""`).